# Get two different list with map

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm continue learning Racket (well, in this case functional programming).

I have to implement this loop in a functional programming way:
[image]

At this moment I have this code:

```
#lang racket

(define EGS0
  (lambda (PSET NSET CSET HSET)
    (map (lambda (h)
           (cond
             [(not (andmap (lambda (p) (my-function h p)) PSET)) h]
             [(not (ormap (lambda (n) (my-function h n)) NSET)) h]
             ) HSET))))
```

Instead of removing elements from `HSET` list, I'm creating a new one with the elements that I don't have to remove. This code is only a **first approximation**: in some cases this will add twice `h` but this is not my problem now.

`CSET` is an empty list and `my-function` returns `#t` or `#f`.

My problem comes with the last statement:

> Then remove H from HSET and add H to CSET.

With `map` and I can get one list, but I don't know how to get two list. the only way I can think of is using `set!`, but if I use it, it is not going to be functional program.

Instead of map, I've thought to use a `for` loop, or maybe do two loops.

How can I get the two lists (the new list with the elements of HSET and the CSET list)?

**UPDATE:**
I'm adding some data to test the algorithm (someone needs extra help to understand the pseudocode).

```
(define my-function (lambda (x y) (and x y)))

(define hset '(1))
(define pset '(0))
(define nset '(1))

(egs pset nset '() hset)
```

It must returns: `'(() (1))`.

Comment: `map` is not the right tool for your task. You want to allow the output list to be potentially shorter than the input list, but `map` will always return a list of the same length. Take a look into [`filter`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) and see how you can utilize it.

Comment: I see you've been struggling with `map` lately. In general, we use `map` when we already have a list, and we want to create a new list _with the same number of elements_, where each output element is the result of applying one function on each of the elements of the input list. And that's it, don't try to use `map` for _everything_ that requires looping.

Comment: In its current state, this question is untestable. Please post some sample input for `hset`, `pset`, `nset` and the expected output for both `hset` and `cset`. Also post the code for `my-function`.

Comment: With the sample input, it's easier to understand what you needed. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that this problem is procedural in nature and is not as straightforward to write in a functional style; in this case writing an explicit loop is more natural than using `map` or `filter`.

Returning two values is easy, it can be managed by passing two accumulator parameters in the recursion and returning them at the end inside a list. Here's my implementation:

```
(define (egs pset nset cset hset)
  (let loop ((input hset) (output '()) (cset cset))
    (if (null? input)
        ; return modified cset and hset
        (list cset output)
        (let ((pset-match
               (andmap (lambda (p) (my-function (car input) p)) pset))
              (nset-match
               (ormap (lambda (n) (my-function (car input) n)) nset)))
          (cond ((not nset-match)
                 ; if h does not match any members from nset
                 ; remove h from hset, add h to cset
                 (loop (cdr input) output (cons (car input) cset)))
                ((not pset-match)
                 ; if h does not match all members of pset
                 ; remove h from hset, leave cset unmodified
                 (loop (cdr input) output cset))
                (else
                 ; otherwise don't remove h from hset, leave cset unmodified
                 (loop (cdr input) (cons (car input) output) cset)))))))
```

It works with the sample input:

```
(define my-function (lambda (x y) (and x y)))

(define hset '(1))
(define pset '(0))
(define nset '(1))

(egs pset nset '() hset)
=> '(() (1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I think this piece of code, `(and (not pset-match) (not nset-match))`, is wrong (or maybe I haven't understood it). I have to add h to cset only when *h does not match any members of NSET*. And in your code you add it when h does not match all PSET **and** any NSET.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my code is doing. Because in the pseudocode they first check if h does not match all members of pset, and in either case we remove the element from hset

Comment: I think the real issue here is: do we interpret the two IFs in the pseudocode as: one first and then the other (doing both _always_) or one first and only if it doesn't succeed the other (doing the second _only_ if the first fails)?

Comment: Maybe you have to put the recursive call outside the `cond` statement and use two auxiliary variables: one for HSET with H remove it or not, and the other one to CSET with H added or not.

Comment: In my code, I interpreted the pseudocode as "doing both IF _always_", and that's why my test is `(and (not pset-match) (not nset-match))`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is with CSET. You have to add H only if **nset-match** is `#t`.

Comment: @VansFannel that's procedural thinking, you'd need to `set!` variables to do that. Why don't you write some tests and check if my answer works? I can't do it, as only you know what you're trying to do, you didn't provide enough context to the question

Comment: "You have to add H only if nset-match is #t". Well, the pseudocode is clear on that: we add to cset only if h doesn't match *any* member of nset, and that's what my code states: `(not nset-match)` means that not a single match was found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189140/discussion-between-vansfannel-and-oscar-lopez).

Comment: I can't chat right now. Please add tests to the question, so we can check which interpretation is correct. The pseudocode is ambiguous.

Comment: We wouldn't be having this conversation if it wasn't ambiguous. If your tests demonstrate that your interpretation is correct, I'll gladly update my answer. Post some sample input hset, pset, nset and the expected output for both hset and cset. Also post the code for my-function.

Comment: If you set `((not nset-match)` as the first condition, it will do the same as in the pseudocode because the second condition contains the first (you can not remove the same element twice from a list).